# I think I damaged the USB ports on my Laptop

Tags: usb, laptop, port, acer

My Laptop model is an Acer Predator Helios 300 G3-572.
I tried using my USB HUB with a Power Supply, but I didn't notice the power supply was 12V.
After connecting the USB HUB, my Laptop shut down. It started back again normally but now the 2 USB 2.0 ports don't work anymore.

Did I fry the USB ports? How hard is it to replace them?

They seem to be separated from the rest of the Motherboard but are together with the Headphone and Laptop AC Adapter connectors (which are fine btw)

[image]
.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have fried either the USB controller or the USB power supply circuit. The connectors themselves should be fine. It's hard to say from the photo where the damaged parts are, but they aren't necessarily located on the daughterboard. The damaged IC will probably have a small crater on it similar to this one:

[image: Photo of a section of a motherboard. Square integrated circuit in the middle is surrounded by a variety of SMD components. In the corner of the IC there's a darker spot and the plastic around it looks slightly deformed.]

If the damage is local to the daughterboard, it should be fixable - probably by replacing the daughterboard. If it's on the motherboard, it may not be possible. Replacing ICs is doable with appropriate equipment and skill, but ICs fried like this can be physically fused with the board and lifting them can do unrepairable damage.

It's probably best to take the laptop to a competent repair shop and ask them what they think about it.

---

For the curious, the photo depicts a power controller for one of the phases of an Intel J4105 CPU. Damage was caused by a faulty pico-style PSU. The motherboard had to be replaced. I think I've found the fault in the PSU and fixed it, but it's waiting for a sacrificial motherboard to test it on.